# SQL - Joining fact and dimension data within Date ranges

Tags: sql-server, join, date-range

I have 2 tables in my sql server database that i would like to join based on their dates range. This data is confidential, i will try to keep this as clear as possible although i got to uncover the data, so i hope you are ok with that.

One of the tables represent transactional data that represents the usage of one certain object that will be invoiced monthly, pls see below a preview of this table

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+
| Object1 ID | Object2 ID |    tFrom   |     tTo    | Transaction Cost |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+
|      54324 | AAA        | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017 | 15,45 €          |
|      54324 | AAA        | 02/01/2017 | 02/01/2017 | 20,00 €          |
|      54324 | AAA        |            | 15/01/2017 | 3,00 €           |
|      54324 | AAA        |            | 02/02/2017 | 2,00 €           |
|      56767 | BBB        |            | 12/12/2017 | 1,78 €           |
|      34567 | BBB        | 02/01/2017 | 02/01/2017 | 40,00 €          |
|      34567 | BBB        | 04/01/2017 | 04/01/2017 | 30,00 €          |
|      34567 | BBB        |            | 16/01/2017 | 9,00 €           |
|      34567 | BBB        | 31/01/2017 | 31/01/2017 | 45,00 €          |
|      85432 | CCC        | 31/12/2016 | 31/12/2016 | 23,00 €          |
|      85432 | CCC        | 02/01/2017 | 02/01/2017 | 12,00 €          |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+
```

As you can see, there are two objects in the table - that is because the usage of the object to be invoiced is dependent of the one other one, and there can be different allocations of object1 and object2 in a monthly basis although the switches between objects are not that frequent.

My dimensions table, contemplates 3 types of services (one of witch is represented in the table above) and holds several user dimensions (i only represented 2 of those so the table won't get too big). This dimensions can vary in a monthly basis. Pls see a preview of this table below:

```
+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Service Type | Person ID | Dimension1 | Dimension2 | Object1 ID | Object2 ID |    dFrom    |     dTo     |
+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Service1     |         1 | wer        | errerr     |      54324 | AAA        | 01/12/2016 | 28/02/2017 |
| Service2     |         1 | wer        | errerr     |      54324 | AAA        | 01/12/2016 | 28/02/2017 |
| Service3     |         1 | wer        | errerr     |      54324 | AAA        | 01/12/2016 | 28/02/2017 |
| Service1     |         2 | qerer      | teety      |      56767 | BBB        | 01/11/2016 | 31/12/2017 |
| Service2     |         2 | qerer      | teety      |      56767 | BBB        | 01/11/2016 | 31/12/2017 |
| Service3     |         2 | qerer      | teety      |      56767 | BBB        | 01/11/2016 | 31/12/2017 |
| Service1     |         3 | ghgh       | ryyyrtq    |      34567 | BBB        | 01/01/2017 | 31/12/2100 |
| Service2     |         3 | ghgh       | ryyyrtq    |      34567 | BBB        | 01/01/2017 | 31/12/2100 |
| Service3     |         3 | ghgh       | ryyyrtq    |      34567 | BBB        | 01/01/2017 | 31/12/2100 |
| Service1     |         4 | tyty       | ty         |      85432 | CCC        | 01/12/2016 | 31/12/2100 |
| Service2     |         4 | tyty       | ty         |      85432 | CCC        | 01/12/2016 | 31/12/2100 |
| Service3     |         4 | tyty       | ty         |      85432 | CCC        | 01/12/2016 | 31/12/2100 |
| Service2     |         5 | gjhh       | tytyrtt    |      98988 |            | 01/12/2016 | 31/12/2100 |
| Service3     |         5 | gjhh       | tytyrtt    |      98988 |            | 01/12/2016 | 31/12/2100 |
+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

The objective here is to allocate the costs from table one, to each person in table 2, like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Object1 ID | Object2 ID |    tFrom   |    tTo     | Transaction Cost | Person ID | Dimension1 | Dimension2 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|      54324 | AAA        | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017 | 15,45 €          |         1 | wer        | errerr     |
|      54324 | AAA        | 02/01/2017 | 02/01/2017 | 20,00 €          |         1 | wer        | errerr     |
|      54324 | AAA        |            | 15/01/2017 | 3,00 €           |         1 | wer        | errerr     |
|      54324 | AAA        | 02/02/2017 |            | 2,00 €           |         1 | wer        | errerr     |
|      56767 | BBB        |            | 12/12/2017 | 1,78 €           |         2 | qerer      | teety      |
|      34567 | BBB        | 02/01/2017 | 02/01/2017 | 40,00 €          |         3 | ghgh       | ryyyrtq    |
|      34567 | BBB        | 04/01/2017 | 04/01/2017 | 30,00 €          |         3 | ghgh       | ryyyrtq    |
|      34567 | BBB        |            | 16/01/2017 | 9,00 €           |         3 | ghgh       | ryyyrtq    |
|      34567 | BBB        | 31/01/2017 | 31/01/2017 | 45,00 €          |         3 | ghgh       | ryyyrtq    |
|      85432 | CCC        | 31/12/2016 | 31/12/2016 | 23,00 €          |         4 | tyty       | ty         |
|      85432 | CCC        | 02/01/2017 | 02/01/2017 | 12,00 €          |         4 | tyty       | ty         |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

To try and solve this on my own, I've googled and the most similar article i found was [this one](https://blog.oraylis.de/2014/11/combining-multiple-tables-with-valid-fromto-date-ranges-into-a-single-dimension/), but unfortunately it doesn't quite fit my needs.
I managed to create an inner join of the tables above based on object1 and object2 ID's and filtering, the dimension table, by the service type and by the date ranges dTo > tTo and dFrom <= tTo. From this inner join i could retrieve some incorrect results, and i think it can be related to the way i defined the date range filters.

What do you guys think about this?
How can i join such tables and produce the results I've showed in the third table?

Edit:
I've just found that in my original tables, there are some transactions identified with object1 ID + Object2 ID in a given period of dates, that are not covered in my dimensions table. Example: Suppose that a given transaction has tTo=02-02-2016 for Object1 ID = 34567 and object2 ID = BBBB but my dimension table has Object1 ID = 45698 and object2 ID = BBBB dFrom  = 10-02-2016 and dTo = 05-06-2016. The dimension table, is a table manually built in a excel file that i submitted to SQL server table through SSIS and its part of an internal process cost allocation that is very basic (to the point that the information it contains is not always exactly what happened in reality and the matching between the transactions table and the dimensions table must be approximated. I've been trying for so many hours now to have some view ready to include all cases,but still unsuccessful. I'm sure this is a basic thing that I'm missing but just don't know what.

Thank you for reading.
Pls let me know if you need more info.

Comment: How does the service type column in the dimension table relate to the two objects?

Comment: Hi Eli, thank you for your feedback! I guess i wasn't too explicit about that, was i? :) Anyway, the object type column is related to the two objects when it is equal to Service1.

Comment: so... when it is service 2 or 3 there's no relation?

Comment: Yes Eli, that's it. I know the table seems a bit awkward, but the dimensions table is produced in a fashion to allow to merge with other fact tables similar to the one described in the post, that relate to services 2 and 3.  I hope its clearer this time around. :)

Comment: It's actually not very clear. Can you please create a fiddle on rextester.com or sqlfiddle? you can use the dummy data in your question and also show what you've tried

Comment: Hi there! I'v just created the fiddle that you were asking. Since it's my first time doing it i hope its good. Here is the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8cc40/1

Comment: How do you have NULL tfrom dates in a fact table?

Comment: Yeah... that's an inherent characteristic, unfortunately. It can happen many times.

Comment: transaction cost in fact_table i daily cost or period cost?

Comment: Its the cost associated with the period beginning in date tFROM and ending in tTO.

Comment: Hi everyone! 
I solved this bugger using power query, but i think the core idea can also be used in SQL.
What i did, was to "convert" the dimensions table to a table were i would have a single row, for a single date where that set of dimensions was active, and join that table to the transactions table,after converting this last table to a single row for each date span interval (where it would apply). I am working with over an year of data and the resulting queries and data model in excel work fairly OK.
 I hope this lead, helps someone with similar problem :)